# $translate.instant does not translate values in AngularJS component when component starts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate, angularjs-components

With [Angular Translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and [$translate.instant()](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate) method I built AngularJS's select component with automatic switching between languages:

```
<translated-select
  elements="$ctrl.values"
  current-value="$ctrl.value"
  on-change="$ctrl.setValue(value)"
></translated-select>
{{ $ctrl.value }}
<hr>
<button ng-click="$ctrl.switchToPolish()">
  Switch to polish
</button>
<button ng-click="$ctrl.switchToEnglish()">
  Switch to english
</button>
```

As you can see on Plunker: [Angular JS select with automated translations](http://plnkr.co/edit/T1Hysr?p=preview). Problem is that it shows `select`s options as undefined until I choose second option. Then everything works, and I can switch between english and polish translations of options. I tried even wait for first change with `$onChanges` hook and if change occurred run `$digest` with `$timeout`:

```
this.$onChanges = function (changes) {
  if (changes.elements) {
    $timeout(function () {
      this.values = changes.elements.currentValue;
    }.bind(this));
  }
  if (changes.currentValue) {
    $timeout(function () {
      this.value = changes.currentValue.currentValue;
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

But again and again, I have to choose second option in select to make it work. Am I missing something? I would be grateful if anybody will help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at https://www.sitepoint.com/multilingual-support-for-angularjs/ and https://scotch.io/tutorials/internationalization-of-angularjs-applications. Both contain good solutions for your issue

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Could you please specify a little bit? Do you mean listening to `$translateChangeSuccess`? I don't think it can change something - once I choose second option everything works well, but if I don't - even if I use 5 second `$timeout` it won't work.

Comment: I meant the part about switching languages without having to reload anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$translate.instant() isn't aware of the fact that the translation might not be loaded completely.

As per [documentation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate#methods_instant):

> Returns a translation instantly from the internal state of loaded
>   translation.

So if you don't rely on $translate.instant() you could also use the translate filter (which uses a watch internally) as follows:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.value"' + 'ng-options="value as (value | translate) for value in $ctrl.values" ' + ' ng-change="$ctrl.onSelect()" ' + '></select>
```

A complete example can be found here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zmYgiOOVjXCmGprsvOLO?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Consider having a try of [`$onInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) instead of `$onChanges`. As from the documentation:

> $onInit() - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.

```
this.$onInit = function() {
  this.values = this.elements;
  this.value = this.currentValue;

  this.onSelect = function() {
    this.onChange({
      value: this.value
    });
  };

  this.translate = function(key) {
    return $translate.instant(key);
  };
};
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/5T90efhcnaQoEGoLY1gZ?p=preview